# Properties.tmpl file in java

Tags: java, properties

I found abc.properties.tmpl file in a java project.Which is similar to abc.properties file.I am not aware why it is important to keep tmpl file in project.
What is the use of this file?

Comment: Hard to tell without knowing the project. Who put the file there? What is in it? Is it processed by your build process or at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned which IDE environment you are using and where (in which folder of the project) you found this, there could be lots of possibilities:

1) This might have been generated or kept by the IDE environment being used e.g. NetBeans, Eclipse. I cannot remember if it's specific to HTML or just any templates that require property settings.

2) This might have been generated by some old application which hasn't been cleaned up.

As I said, you have to update the question with more relevant information (perhaps some screenshots/snippets) for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The file might have been copied twice and renamed. Or the guy created the tmpl file as a backup while working on abc.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Not known, "tmpl" would be "template." When there are multiple locales, en_US, nl_NL, nl, nl_BE they all are placed in their own properties file, having the same keys but different language texts.

So the tmpl file might be for a new language, or when a key/text is added, so all other properties must be updated by doing a text diff.

My guess is, that the tmpl file does not need to be distributed. Check the produced jar, the build, references to tmpl.